# Adding a comment to NHibernate Envers Revision Entity

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I've got basic Envers working, and I understand how to get something like the name of the calling User into the Revision Entity, since that's effective static data.  But how do I add a comment created dynamically by the user for a given revision?

I suppose I can find some way by subclassing some of the listeners and/or classes used by the listeners (or just implementing their interfaces), but if anyone out there has done this already I'd really appreciate an example.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You write you know how to set some name of the user committing the transaction. I guess therefore you know about the `IRevisionListener` interface - there you can modify you revision entity before it is saved.

Depending on what host/client/process you run your application on, you need to set the "comment" in some suitable scope. Assuming you're using web app, you can eg set the comment on some `HttpContext` item and get this value in your `IRevisionListener`.

Comment: You're correct, and I did understand about implementing IRevisionListener, but I didn't like the fact that the listeners in the examples had to reach out to some framework to get the data.  In the end, I didn't find a better way than to just make Comment a static member of the listener class, set it in my application and then copy it into the revision info in the listener.